# Is it possible to uninstall ruby gems, rails etc and do a complete clean install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, osx-snow-leopard

I seem to be having issues with gems and want to start with a fresh install. Is this possible without re-installing Snow Leopard from scratch?

Comment: I am taking a wild guess, but are you having issues with Ruby and MySQL? That is a common problem on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution will be to check out [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/). It lets you have multiple Ruby environments (each with their own set of gems) installed in parallel, which makes it easy to "start fresh" and built the environment from the ground up.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to uninstall before using RVM (which is indeed the recommended solution), check [this blog post by Chad Wooley](http://pivotallabs.com/removing-old-ruby-after-a-leopard-upgrade/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can forget all about the gems on your system's Ruby and install RVM.  [This guide](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyversionmanager/ss/Installing-Ruby-On-Snow-Leopard-With-Rvm.htm), complete with screenshots, will show you how.  Then you can use [gemsets](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyversionmanager/a/Using-Rvm-Gemsets.htm) to keep things organized and, if you wish, delete all your gems at any time and start over.